# $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(x,n)=\frac{d}{dx}\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x, n)$?

Tags: limits, derivatives

My question is probably very simple to answer. Are these two expressions equivalent (assuming the limit exists)?

$
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{d}{dx}f(x,n)=\frac{d}{dx}\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x, n)
$

Thank you very much,

Best regards
Kevin

Comment: Is the accepted answer really what you look for? The limit $\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(x,n)$ might depend on $x$. I guess you mean that the limit should exist for all $x$ (but not necessarily be the same for all $x$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $$f(x, n) = x\ - \ {1\over n}tan^{-1}(nx)$$ for all $$ n \ \epsilon\ N$$
Then $${d\over dx}f(x, n) = 1 - {1\over n^2x^2 + 1} = {x^2\over x^2 + {1\over n^2}}$$ Thus $${d\over dx}f(0, n) = 0$$ and hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{d\over dx}f(0, n) = 0$$
**However, since** $$tan^{-1}nx<\pi/2$$ for all values of x and n $\epsilon$ N, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{1\over n}tan^{-1}nx = 0$$ and we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x, n) = x$$ Therefore $$\left ( {d\over dx}\lim_{n\to \infty}f(x, n) \right )(0) = {dx\over dx} = 1$$ **Thus the two limits are not always equal**.